# Find overdue dates in range excel

Tags: excel, date, indexing, match, vlookup

I need to return an item number where the date related is overdue (the date is before today).  Row 1 would have the dates - most are in the future, and row 4 would have the item number.

Example:

```
     A           B          C           D  
1 01/09/18   18/10/15   01/04/16    22/03/23  
2  
3  
4 01D23       83E12      24D21       95C08
```

So, the results would be `83E21` and `24D21` (with today's date being 23/06/17).  This would be shown on another `results` tab as this will need to be applied on multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The data layout with the dates going across the columns is not the best for processing with out of the box tools. If the data was flipped by 90 degrees, you could use a filter on the date column.

In the screenshot, you'd select the dropdown in cell A1, then Filter, then Before and then select today's date.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I need to pull the results into another tab, though.  Due to a lot of other data and calculations, the way we have it is necessary.

Comment: In that case you will need VBA. In the long run, it might be worth revisiting the data architecture. It's hard to maintain solutions on bad architecture.